# Tidy to xhtml with parameters such as allowFullScreen

Tags: php, tidy, htmltidy

I'm parsing simple oembed urls from youtube, and converting them to xhtml, however, some html gets tidy'd (I believe to be) incorrectly.  Shouldn't the valid xhtml be allowFullScreen="true"?????  If this is correct, is there some tidy module that will do that?  I must I go the "purifier" route?

**input from youtube:**

```
<iframe allowfullscreen ... ></iframe>
```

**final output after tidy'ing:**

```
<iframe allowfullscreen="" ...></iframe>
```

**PHP Tidy:**

```
$tidy                   =  new \tidy();
$config             =  array(
    'show-body-only'   => true,
    'char-encoding'    => 'utf8'
);
$output = $tidy -> repairString($data['html'], $config, 'UTF8');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any XHTML specification that defines an `allowfullscreen` attribute, which would explain why tidy isn't recognising it as a boolean attribute.

If it is a boolean attribute, then `true` would not be a valid value for it. The name and the value would be the same string.